# Optimize a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, optimization, dplyr

df_data is a dataframe of 40 000 rows and 30 columns, in the for loop I try to add many columns  (approx 600), it works but it s very very slow, I try to work with different alternative like apply but i cannot achieve the same result. Is there a way to simultaneous add all the value for one row ?

```
    df_i_final <- data.frame()
    start<- Sys.time()

    for (i in 1:nrow(df_data)) {

      row <- df_data[i, ]

      varname_1 <- paste("1",row["CATEGORIE"],row["RANK"],row["MD"],"a", sep="_")
      varname_2 <- paste("2",row["CATEGORIE"],row["RANK"],row["MD"],"b", sep="_")
      varname_3 <- paste("3",row["CATEGORIE"],row["RANK"],row["MD"],"c", sep="_")
      varname_4 <- paste("4",row["CATEGORIE"],row["RANK"],row["MD"],"d", sep="_")
      varname_5 <- paste("5",row["CATEGORIE"],row["RANK"],row["MD"],"e", sep="_")
      varname_6 <- paste("aa",row["CATEGORIE"],row["RANK"],row["MD"],"fg", sep="_")
      varname_7 <- paste("aa",row["CATEGORIE"],row["RANK"],row["MD"],"fg", sep="_")
      varname_8 <- paste("aa",row["CATEGORIE"],row["RANK"],row["MD"],"fg", sep="_")
      varname_9 <- paste("aa",row["CATEGORIE"],row["RANK"],row["MD"],"fg", sep="_")

      if (row["VAL1"] > 0 | row["VAL2"] > 0 | row["VAL3"] > 0 | row["VAL4"] > 0 | row["VAL5"] > 0 | row["VAL6"] > 0 | row["VAL7"] > 0 )
      {
      df_i_final[i, "IDENT"] <- row["IDENT"]
      if (row["VAL1"] > 0) df_i_final[i, varname_1] <- row["VAL1"]
      if (row["VAL2"] > 0) df_i_final[i, varname_2] <- row["VAL2"] 
      if (row["VAL3"] > 0) df_i_final[i, varname_3] <- row["VAL3"]
      if (row["VAL4"] > 0) df_i_final[i, varname_4] <- row["VAL4"]
      if (row["VAL5"] > 0) df_i_final[i, varname_5] <- row["VAL5"]
      if (row["VAL6"] > 0) df_i_final[i, varname_6] <- row["VAL6"]
      if (row["VAL7"] > 0) df_i_final[i, varname_7] <- row["VAL7"]
      }
    }

    process_time<- Sys.time() - start
    print(format(process_time))
```

Edit : I add some sample and I try your code which works to create the columns but when it set the values, it should only update columns with the same categorie name...

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("1100455", "1100455", "1100455", "1100455", "1100455", "1100464", "1100464"),
                  CATEGORIE = c("10110", "10160", "10604", "11220", "90310", "10110","10140"),
                  RANK =  c("1", "1", "1", "1", "0" ,"1", "1"),
                  MD =  c("0", "0", "0", "3", "4", "0", "0" ),
                  PROD3 = c(2345.00,1114.58,501.40,0.00,0.00,2720.00,636.80),
                  VALUE3 = c(540.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00),
                  AREA3 = c(563.76,0.00,17.35,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00),
                  LONG3 = c(4100,2100,1740,265,0,3978,940)
)


nm1 <-c("PROD3")
nm1
i1 <- Reduce(`|`, lapply(df2[nm1], `>`, 0))
newvars <- paste("aa",df2[["CATEGORIE"]],df2[["RANK"]],df2[["MD"]],"ta", sep="_")
newvars <- unique(newvars)
newvars
df2[newvars] <- NA
df2[i1, newvars] <- df2[i1, nm1]
df2
```

here all the colums with differents name's categorie are updated,It has to be only the ones that match the categorie value (so only aa_10110_1_0_ta here )

```
       ID CATEGORIE RANK MD   PROD3 VALUE3  AREA3 LONG3 aa_10110_1_0_ta aa_10160_1_0_ta aa_10604_1_0_ta aa_11220_1_3_ta aa_90310_0_4_ta aa_10140_1_0_ta
1 1100455     10110    1  0 2345.00    540 563.76  4100         2345.00         2345.00         2345.00         2345.00         2345.00         2345.00
```

Comment: Can you add a small reproducible example with dput

Comment: I edit my first post, but i think what I m looking for is a spread function

Answer (score 2):

We could vectorize this.  Loop over the columns of interest with `lapply`, check if it is greater than 0, `Reduce` to a single logical vector with `|`, Use that to create new columns with the corresponding values in that columns

```
nm1 <- paste0('VAL', 1:7)
i1 <- Reduce(`|`, lapply(df_i_final[nm1], `>`, 0))
newvars <- paste(seq_len(nrow(df_i_final)), 
     df_i_final[["CATEGORIE"]],df_i_final[["RANK"]],df_i_final[["MD"]],"a", sep="_")
df_i_final[newvars] <- NA
df_i_final[i1, newvars] <- df_i_final[i1, nm1]
```